# Writing random numbers with no duplicate using only Random without ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random, numbers

I have a problem to write more lucidity program for random numbers without repeating. My code works but its not really nice.

I tried many thinks especially i just played with loops

```
for(int i=1; i<=pole.length;i++){

   while(p<=13){
     i=rd.nextInt(13)+1;
     if(pole[i]==i){    
     }
     else{
        System.out.println`(i+"-"+p);
        pole[i]=i;
        p++;
        if(i>Max){
          Max=i;
        }
    }
  i=Max;
}
```

I expect 13 numbers without repeating this one works but how to write it easier

Comment: Use an `ArrayList`. It's not so bad. Look, three lines of code: `List<Integer> al = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,13).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  Collections.shuffle(al);
  System.out.println(al);`

Comment: There is many ways how to do that but looks like my teacher wants most complicated way how to do that. Its really easy in my head it works but in Netbeans not :) :) .

Answer (score 0):

i try to solve you problem 
1st way:

```
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[13];
        int i = 0;
        for (;;) {
            if (i == 13) {
                break;
            }
            int random = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

            if (!Arrays.asList(arr).contains(random)) {
                arr[i] = random;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

2nd way:

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
     while (list.size()<13) {  
        Integer random = (int )(Math.random() * 100);
        if(!list.contains(random)){
            list.add(random);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you do not want to use Collections.shuffle(), you can also achieve the same using Set.

```
  Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
  while (set.size() < 13)
    set.add((int) (Math.random() * 101));
```

Please keep in mind, you will also have to check if the random number range is much greater than the set size (In the above example, you need to make sure 101 is always greater than the number of unique numbers needed i.e 13, else you would end up in a very long/infinite while loop)